# WIndows Phone Certification Test Results - Fail

Tags: windows-phone-7

The second time refused to certify the application.

```
Comments: The application's long description and/or UI content is presented in Ukrainian not natively supported in the OS. 
For an application to be presented in a language not natively supported in the OS, its description must satisfy the following 
requirements:
1. A statement to indicate the application is not in the targeted language.
2. A full description text in the targeted language.
3. A full description text in the language supported by the application.
```

The second time I have a description in targeted language and supported by thr application, but App Center refused to certify the application again.
What did I do wrong?

What is mean this point?

```
1. A statement to indicate the application is not in the targeted language.
```

I'm not sure what to do.

When I must do description text in target lang and supported by the app?

Thanks.

Comment: It means you must include a statement to say that "this app is not in English, it is in Ukrainian" or something along those lines.

Comment: But where I must include this? When I submited my app, I include both long description and wrote to Certification notes that my app is not in English. but received a refusal to back again

Comment: I think what it says is that you need a full description in english aswell?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had this problem when I submitted Swedish apps to the Marketplace before Sweden got support. What I did was to have the app description like this:

> NOTE: This application is only in Swedish.
>
> Full description in Swedish
>
> -- English --
>
> Full description in English

And after that the app was certified without any problems. So change Swedish to Ukrainian and you should be fine.

Comment: thanks, small questions: 1) I can publish my app in all markets in the world? 2) In which field I must describe NOTE with full description? Is it "Certification notes" or "Description for the Store"?

Comment: 1) Yes you can.
2) The text should go in the "Description for the Store" field.